How to incorporate argparse into a python function with two arguments
I am trying to figure out how to incorporate argparse into a python function I have created that accepts two arguments, so that it is executable in the command line.
For example in this function below:
def function(arg1, arg2):
        print(arg1 * arg2)

How could I implement argparse to be able to execute the following in the command line:
% python3 pythonscript.py function arg1 arg2

I have tried to use argparse, but I have only found tutorials for how to use it on python scripts and not functions.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? The only use for argparse is to process command line arguments to a Python script, it has nothing to do with functions. You can of course create a script that calls a function with some of those arguments when executed, but the name of the parameters doesn't have to relate to functions actually in your script. It's bad practice to make a user of a script that needs to use if from the CLI have to know about the contents of your script and the names used therein.

I don't understand your problem - to run some function you have to run script. And this script has to get args (e.g using sys.argv or argparse) and execute function with these args.

BTW: return doesn't need =. And if you want to see result in command line then you have to use print() instead of return

@Grismar While I mostly agree, argparse would provide the user with the necessary help, so code inspection by the user is not necessary. Specifically, click is a library that cleanly marries argparse with functions, much like OP wants. That said, I believe OP needs some more basics in Python, and should save click for when they understand more about how Python and its scripts work.

To run function you have to load script - and this script has to get arguments and use it to execute expected function with expected values.
To get arguments you can use sys.argv, argparse and it will need to recognize function's name and run it. Other modules - like click, google/python-fire, invoke - can make it simpler because they can recognize function automatically and execute it.
For the beginning I show example with sys.argv
import sys

"""
% python3 script.py mul 1 2
% python3 script.py add 1 2
"""

def mul(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 * arg2 

def add(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2 

# --- main ---

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    print("Usage: python3 script.py function arg1 arg2")
    exit(1)
    
name = sys.argv[1]
val1 = int(sys.argv[2])
val2 = int(sys.argv[3])

if name == "mul":
    result = mul(val1, val2)
    print(result)
elif name == "add":
    result = add(val1, val2)
    print(result)
else:
    print("wrong function's name")

And the same with dictionary (instead of many if/else) to execute function:
import sys

"""
% python3 script.py mul 1 2
% python3 script.py add 1 2
"""

def mul(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 * arg2 

def add(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2 

# --- main ---

if len(sys.argv) < 4:
    print("Usage: python3 script.py function arg1 arg2")
    exit(1)
    
name = sys.argv[1]
val1 = int(sys.argv[2])
val2 = int(sys.argv[3])

functions = {
    "mul": mul,
    "add": add,
}

if name in functions:
    result = functions[name](val1, val2)
    print(result)
else:
    print("wrong function's name")

And simular for argparse.
argparse may use options which may allow to send more complex parameters - like skip parameters to use default values, etc. - so it is more useful than sys.argv
I added option --debug to display extra information
import argparse

"""
% python3 script.py --help
% python3 script.py mul 1 2
% python3 script.py add 1 2
% python3 script.py -D mul 1 2
% python3 script.py -D add 1 2
% python3 script.py --debug mul 1 2
% python3 script.py --debug add 1 2
"""

def mul(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 * arg2 

def add(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2 

# --- main ---

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('name')
parser.add_argument('val1')
parser.add_argument('val2')

parser.add_argument('-D', '--debug', action='store_true', help='[default: %(default)s]')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.debug:
   print("args:", args)

name = args.name
val1 = int(args.val1)
val2 = int(args.val1)

functions = {
    "mul": mul,
    "add": add,
}

if name in functions:
    if args.debug:
        print("executing:", functions[name], "with", val1, val2)
    result = functions[name](val1, val2)
    print(result)
else:
    print("wrong function's name")

With click it can be simpler but it needs to add decorators.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import click

"""
% python3 script.py mul 1 2
% python3 script.py add 1 2
"""

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass
    
@click.command()
@click.argument('arg1', type=click.INT)
@click.argument('arg2', type=click.INT)
def mul(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1 * arg2)

@click.command()
@click.argument('arg1', type=click.INT)
@click.argument('arg2', type=click.INT)
def add(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1 + arg2)

cli.add_command(mul)
cli.add_command(add)

# --- main ---

cli()

The same with fire can be even simpler
import fire

"""
% python3 script.py mul 1 2
% python3 script.py add 1 2
"""

class Calculator:

    def mul(self, arg1, arg2):
        return arg1 * arg2

    def add(self, arg1, arg2):
        return arg1 + arg2

# --- main ---

fire.Fire(Calculator)


Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Do it like this:
import sys

def function(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 * arg2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    function(*args)

However, it isn't possible to call a python function object via the command-line. Only python files and scripts or other executable files can be executed via command-line. In the above code, the arguments are first parsed by the sys library's .argv variable which is a list (no need to use argparse here). Then the arguments are sliced by [1:], removing the first argument which is usually the path of the file. Finally, the arguments are unpacked and passed into the function by the line function(*args). All of this code is surrounded by a if __name__ == '__main__': check which is essential for determining whether or not this file is executed directly or is just being imported (in which case we do not want the block to execute.).
